# Is it possible to create a pure ajax application with MVC4?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I heard it is possible to create a pure ajax application with ASP.NET web form using web services. What about with MVC4? Is there anyway I can create a pure ajax application with MVC4? If so, how should I begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is ASP.Net Single Page Application (SPA) which sits on top of MVC4.  Look at [www.asp.net/single-page-application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application) for the nitty gritty.